# selecting a number from a string with period

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the below XML code

```
<table>    
  <row>
    <entry>
      <para>2.</para>
    </entry>
    <entry>
      <para>Proceeding relating to the winding-up of companies.</para>
    </entry>
  </row>
  <row>
    <entry>
      <para>3.</para>
    </entry>
    <entry>
      <para>Non-contentious or common form probate proceedings.</para>
    </entry>
  </row>
</table>
```

I want to differentiate using an XSL like if the para element has numbers(2., 3.) it should say

```
<div class="numbers">2.</div>
```

else it should show as below

```
<div class="text">Proceeding relating to the winding-up of companies.</div>
```

Can someone give me direction on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

in XSLT 1 you can use something like

```
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="number(entry[1]/para[1])=number(entry[1]/para[1])=">
       it is a number
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      Not a number
     </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
```

This works as for any number a=a but on a general text number() returns NaN which is not equal to itself.

Comment: hi @David thanks for reply. sorry to say that i didn't understand the explanation that you mentioned below the answer. i want is if there is any number followed by a period (though it is like 150.), in entry. it should surround that number by a div class=para. Thanks again